# Modulus in for-loop no output

Tags: c, modulo

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int num = 90;
    for (int x = 0; x <= num; x++) {
        printf("%d", num % x);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

My code doesn't seem to do anything.

I wanted my code to print the remainders if we divide 0 to 90 to 90 but my code doesn't seem to do anything, please help. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your program does not print anything because it crashes at the first iteration of the loop when computing `num % x` for `x = 0`. This is a division by `0`, which has undefined behavior and stops the program on most current systems.

Start the loop at `1` to avoid this case.

Also output a newline after each value to make the output readable:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int num = 90;
    for (int x = 1; x <= num; x++) {
        printf("%d\n", num % x);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This code will result in a runtime error as it is dividing by zero in the first iteration of the loop, which is undefined behavior in C programming language.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int num = 90;
    for (int x = 1; x <= num; x++) {
        printf("%d", num % x);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How does this add anything not already in the existing answer?

Comment: When I was writing the answer, someone responded, so I did not know that someone had already answered.